# MySQL duplicate check won't work

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

I'm trying to let users upload something to my website's database, but I want to check if it's already there before I let them upload it. Right now all of my code has been written in Dreamweaver in the first code block, except the isO function was part of my attempt to get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php require_once('../Connections/Main.php'); ?>
    <?php
    if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
    {
    if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
    }

    $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

    switch ($theType) {
     case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
     }
     return $theValue;
     }
     }

     mysql_select_db($database_Main, $Main);
     $query_youtube = "SELECT video_id FROM youtube";
     $youtube = mysql_query($query_youtube, $Main) or die(mysql_error());
     $row_youtube = mysql_fetch_assoc($youtube);
     $totalRows_youtube = mysql_num_rows($youtube);

     $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
     if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
     $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
     }

     function isO($sample) {
     mysql_select_db($database_Main, $Main);
    $dbunames = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM youtube WHERE video_id='".$sample."'", $Main);
    echo ($dbunames);
    if(mysql_num_rows($dbunames) == $sample ) { //check if there is already an entry for that username
    echo "this video has alreday been submited";
    return false ;
    } else {
    return true;
    }
    }

    $pieces = explode("=", $_POST['url']);
    $Ndone = $pieces[1];
    $pieces = explode("&", $Ndone);
    $done = $pieces[0];
        if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "youtube" && isO($done))) {

        $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO youtube (video_id) VALUES (%s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($done, "text"));

         $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $Main) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>

         <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="../SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="../SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        </head>
        <style type="text/css">
        .text_box {
    text
    font-size: 9px;
    color: #000;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
     <?php 
     if (isset($_POST['url'])){
    echo "YouTube Video Submited";
    }
?>
     <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" name="youtube" height="100px" method="POST" id="youtube">
    <span id="url">
    <input type="text" class="text_box" value="type in url of video " name="url" id="url2" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
    </input>
    <input type="submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="youtube" />
    </p>
    </input>
    </form>
    <?php ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("url", "url", {validateOn:        ["blur"]});
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    mysql_free_result($youtube);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($dbunames) == $sample )
```

to this

```
if(mysql_num_rows($dbunames) >= 1)
```

`mysql_num_rows` count the number of rows returned. If even 1 row is returned, a record with id of `$sample` already exists in your table

Comment: sorry i acsidently hit enter.

Comment: Ahh, i did it again. when i try that i get this errer "
Warning: mysql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/content/95/8201295/html/dialog/youtube-up.php on line 46

Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/content/95/8201295/html/dialog/youtube-up.php on line 47

Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/content/95/8201295/html/dialog/youtube-up.php on line 49"

Comment: That error means that there is a problem connecting to your database.